# Java .stream().findAny() throws NullpointerException

Tags: java-8, java-stream

My goal is to check if there is a object with specific ID in collection:

```
Optional<PolicyCoHolder> policyHolder = policyCoHolderCollection.getPolicyCoHolder()
    .stream()
    .filter(coHolder -> coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId().longValue() == representativeId)
    .findAny();
```

My collection:

```
policyCoHolder = {ArrayList@17539}  size = 3
 0 = {PolicyCoHolder@17541} 
 1 = {PolicyCoHolder@17542} 
 2 = {PolicyCoHolder@17543}
```

And representativeId:

```
representativeId = null
```

As stated in docs:

> Returns: an Optional describing some element of this stream, or an
>   empty Optional if the stream is empty
>
> Throws: NullPointerException - if the element selected is null

However in my collection there's no null elements, and **.filter()** should have filtered out all elements, so why is **NPE** thrown?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at gold.core.domain.mtpl.mapper.MTPLMapper.lambda$addPolicyCoHolder$1(MTPLMapper.java:303)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findAny(ReferencePipeline.java:469)
```

Comment: Add exception stack trace to the question. Most likely `coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId()` returns `null`, but it's impossible to tell without actual exception.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Updated question with stack trace.

Comment: Yes, just as I suspected. `coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId().longValue() == representativeId` throws the exception. Two possibilities: `getPolicyCoHolderId()` returns `null` or `representativeId` is `null` (if that's not primitive, which I have no way of knowing right now).

Comment: Yes, representativeId was null, i've missed that it's not a primitive...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `coHolder` is `null` or `coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId()`  returns `null`. Try to add additional `filters` before your original filter:

```
Optional<PolicyCoHolder> policyHolder = policyCoHolderCollection.getPolicyCoHolder()
    .stream()
    // will filter out all nulls in the stream
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
    // compare values finally, Object::equals can handle null checks properly
    .filter(coHolder -> Objects.equals(coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId(),representativeId))
.findAny();
```

Of course we can combine all 3 filter into 1, but in my opinion it looks less readable.

Comment: The problem was that representativeId is Long, and it was null. That's where i the exception occured. I've got so fixated on stream and collection that i've missed it...

Comment: When you use `.filter(coHolder -> Objects.equals(coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId(), representativeId))` (without  the `.longValue()`), then you don’t need the preceding `.filter(coHolder -> Objects.nonNull(coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId())`, which is, by the way, overusing the `Objects` methods. `coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId() != null` is simpler than `Objects.nonNull(coHolder.getPolicyCoHolderId()`.

Comment: @Holger, as usual you are right. `Object::equals` handles null cases.

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc, no need to do `longValue()`. `Objects::equals` accepts only boxed values, no need to unbox `policyCoHolderId` just to immediately box it again (and improved readability too).